# Change domain home directory to a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I'm want to move the home directory for the main domain on the host to a sub-directory so all the other domains, sub domains are not mixed with the folders from the website on the main domain.

Example on how I would want to have the folders organised on my host:

Current location for main domain: public_html/index.php

New location for main domain: public_html/old_main/index.php

After the changes when accessing the main domain the url should be the same.

I've found these conditions but they mess up all my other domains. The one that I want redirected works just fine. I don't know how to exclude the others.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.mysite.com/   [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ drupal/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/drupal%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* drupal/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* drupal/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
```

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: Tell me what do you want to rewrite for what and i will help you: Example: `/admin.php?menu=text` to `/admin/text.html`

Comment: @androbin I want my websites to be a bit more organised. Example: `domain1.com to be in /domain1/index.php`; `domain2.com to be in /domain2/index.php`. Currently the main domain is in the root folder and and I want to move it to an sub-directory.

Comment: That's your entire htaccess file? Where is the conditions that messed up all your other domains?

Comment: @JonLin Yes, that's my entire file. I don't know much about .htaccess conditions, that is just an example I found. When I said that it messes up my other domains I meant that they all get redirected to the main domain.